# Windows 12 server NON .COM domain TXT records cannot be found

Tags: iis

I have a windows server running a website for truckersbrew.coffee and cannot see any of the TXT records using external tools available on the internet.  I can browse to the website on the internet with no issues.  So I'm assuming IIS is setup properly.

What do I have to do to allow the DNS lookup tool to see the TXT records.  I have other sites set up on the same server and they all work fine.  It must be something with the .COFFEE extension??

Comment: Did you actually create a TXT record? Show what you configured.

Comment: What do these TXT records have to do with your website? What TXT records have you created? I don't see ant TXT records for the domain when I query for TXT records.

Comment: That's the problem.  I have created the TXT records.  They don't show up when you do the query.  I have another website on the same server (ilcxosa.com).  The TXT records for that domain do come up.  It seems to have something to do with being a .COFFEE instead of a .COM domain name.